# Digitalocean space access denied

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, amazon-s3

I created a digital ocean storage space. The url of the space is as
`https://storagespace.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`
However, when I click on the url to open on the browser I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<BucketName>storagespace</BucketName>
<RequestId>tx000000000000001618a5e-0081246af3-1805687a-nyc3c</RequestId>
<HostId>1805987a-nyc3c-nyc3-zg03</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have no idea what this error means or why I'm having it. I connected the s3 bucket with my django website and the static files are not being served to the browser as well, instead I get 403 forbidden error. Please how do I remove this `access denied` error?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr follow their official tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-scalable-django-app-with-digitalocean-managed-databases-and-spaces

Unfortunately, we don't really know what packages you're using (like are you using Django-storages to to get those static files to S3?). I have no experience with digital ocean, but here are some things to try:

- Install Django-storages. Create an IAM role in AWS that gives full S3 access to only that bucket. Unfortunately, I've got no experience with digital ocean, so I have no idea if you're even able to do that.
- Look around the digital ocean website to see if they have their own way of uploading Django static files. For example, here's the Official Digital Ocean tutorial provided by Digital Ocean for Django with Django-storages: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-scalable-django-app-with-digitalocean-managed-databases-and-spaces

As you can see in the tutorial, they have these settings which I presume digital ocean has provided you:

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

# Moving static assets to DigitalOcean Spaces as per:
# https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-object-storage-with-django
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your_spaces_access_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your_spaces_secret_key'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'your_space_name'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'spaces_endpoint_URL'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'spaces_edge_endpoint_URL'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

Comment: Thanks so much @acw. I'm using django_storge and boto3; and I created the aws s3 bucket on digital ocean because digital ocean linked aws bucket storage to their platform, perhaps for better management. I already followed digitalocean tutorial and I have the last code snippet in your answer to my project `settings.py`. The issue still persists.

Comment: @C-Bizz try adding `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` Two resources that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629252/unable-to-view-files-on-aws-s3-403-forbidden and https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were missing `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'` in your `settings.py` at the time you ran `python manage.py collectstatic`.  Now, you need to go back and set the permission on all the files throwing `403 Forbidden` error manually to `public-read`.  I'd suggest to also add `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'` to your settings for future `collectstatic` commands.